# phonegap-plugin-push using data payload only replaces existing notification

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin

I am using `phonegap-plugin-push` with `Ionic3`.

In the plugin-push [documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/README.md)

they are saying that on Android device we should use only `data` payload and not the  `notification` in order the `on('notification')` will be triggered.

So far so good, but sending only the data payload, causing the notification tray to replace/overrides existing notification previously sent.

When sending `notification` payload, a new notification enters the notification tray without replacing existing one, but on tap event not triggered.

How can I achive both behaviors?

My payload:

```
{
   "message":{

      "android":
      {
         "data":{

            "title":"Hello",
            "body":"Hello",
            "timestamp":"2018-12-20T09:56:55.3250752+02:00"
         }
      },
      "apns":{
         "payload":{
            "aps":{
               "alert":{
                  "title":"Hello",
                  "body":"Hello",
                  "timestamp":"2018-12-20T09:56:55.3250752+02:00"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "token": "f9j....."
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a unique `notId` property in `data` payload solved the problem

```
{
   "message":{

      "android":
      {
         "data":{
            "title":"Hello",
            "body":"Hello",
            "notId": "1646269",
            "timestamp":"2018-12-20T09:56:55.3250752+02:00"
         }
      },
      "apns":{
         "payload":{
            "aps":{
               "alert":{
                  "title":"Hello",
                  "body":"Hello",
                  "timestamp":"2018-12-20T09:56:55.3250752+02:00"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "condition": "'topic.test' in topics"
   }
}
```